# JPA delete does not executed

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, repository

I cannot delete from DB if I throw an exception immediately on the next line.

```
public void verifyExpiration(RefreshToken token) {
    if (token.getExpiryDate().compareTo(Instant.now()) < 0) {
        this.delete(token.getToken());
        throw new TokenException("Refresh token was expired: " + token.getToken());
    }
}

public void delete(String token) {
    this.refreshTokenRepository.deleteByToken(token);
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: If you throw the exception in the thread your all JPA transactions will be rolled back. Are you using SpringBoot?

Comment: That's new. Yes its Spring Boot. Is there a way?

Comment: Please check details below in answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SpringBoot if you want to complete the transaction while exception is also thrown you can use `noRollbackFor` for `@Transactional` annotation as below:

```
@Transactional(noRollbackFor=TokenException.class)
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring repositories are already annotated with `@Transactional`. Which means if an error is thrown while proccessing your data all the flow would be rollbacked.

If you want to disable the trnasactional process of the spring repository you need to redifine the `delete` method in your interface and annotate it with `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTED)` check [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Propagation.html#SUPPORTS)